# Google Map API V3: How to add Custom data to markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is there a way I can add some custom information to my markers for later use. There are ways to have an info-window and a title, but what If I want to associate the marker with other information.

I have other stuff being displayed on the page that depends on the markers so when a marker is click the content on the page has to change depending upon which marker was clicked.I would like store and retrieve the custom data  once a marker is lets say clicked etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 230, accepted):

As a Google Marker is a JavaScript object, you may add custom information in the form `key: value`, where key is a valid string. They are called *object properties* and can be approached in many different ways. The value can be anything legal, as simple as numbers or strings, and also functions, or even other objects. Three simple ways: in the declaration, dot notation and square brackets

```
var markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    customInfo: "Marker A"
});

var markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-10, 0)
});
markerB.customInfo = "Marker B";

var markerC = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-20, 0)
});
markerC['customInfo'] = "Marker C";
```

Then to retrieve it in a similar manner:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerA, 'click', function() {
    alert(this.customInfo);
});
```

Comment: There’s nothing in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) formalizing this pattern. Here’s hoping they do rather than break it in a later version.

Comment: Property 'customInfo' does not exist on type 'Marker'.

Comment: If you're using typescript, you may want to use the brackets rather than the dot to assign such properties

Comment: Using Typescript, there will be an error at line `customInfo: "Marker A"`
To prevent this error, you can add in the previous line:
// @ts-ignore

Answer (score 14):

You can add your own custom properties to the markers (just be careful not to conflict with the API's properties).